# Change keyframe interval using android camera

Tags: android, android-camera, keyframe

Is there a way of changing the frequency of a `keyframe` when using the android camera? I'm using an intent to record video, and then the `MediaMetaDataRetriever` class to extract frames, but the `keyframes` are too far apart for my liking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getFrameAtTime (long timeUs, int option) using OPTION_CLOSEST to get a frame that is not a key frame, so you can access any frame you want.

The only problem is that this frame is not a key frame so it can be pixelated.